# Moving an object according to the direction button in WP8 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to move an object according to the direction buttons *Up,Left,Right,Down.*

I am setting the margin property like:-

```
    img.Margin = new Thickness(l, t, r, b); //L T R B
```

I am *incrementing/decrementing* the values according to the desired movement needed.

I am able to move the object through the click event. **However, I'd like to move the object in the desired direction whenever the button is pressed and held for the user. As soon as the user releases the button the movement should also stop.**

I tried using the hold event, but the operation executed once and then stopped.

On another attempt I tried looping my statements but the App stalled.

Kindly help me out. Thanks!

**EDIT:-**

I handled the ManipulationStarted,ManipulationDelta,ManipulationCompleted events.

Now, I'm able to move my object whenever I'm pressing and holding the button. **However, the new problem that I'm facing is that I have to constantly keep my finger moving on the screen so as to perform the motion.**

The code for the Up Button(the button that moves the object in the vertical direction) is:-

```
    public double l = 0.0, t = 0.0, r = 0.0, b = 0.0;
    public void move()
    {
        img.Margin = new Thickness(l, t, r, b); //L T R B
    }

    private void up_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void up_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        t = t + 1.0;
        move();
    }

    private void up_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I'm not sure whether this method is correct or not. Do advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You should use `ManipulationStarted` and `ManipulationCompleted` events. They works for `Tap` and `Hold` gestures as stated here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff426933(v=vs.105).aspx</s>

**Update**

To correctly detect the beginning and the end of a tap, I suggest using `MouseEnter`and `MouseLeaving` events.
Here a sample which shows how I'm moving down an object.
This is currently a square in the centre of the screen:

```
<Grid x:Name="objectToMove" Background="red" Height="100" Width="100">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="verticalTransform" Y="0" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);

System.Threading.Timer dt;

private void toggle_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dt = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(MoveFunct), autoEvent, 0, 1);
}

private void MoveFunct(Object stateInfo)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { verticalTransform.Y += 3; });
}

private void toggle_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dt.Dispose();
}
```

Note that the last parameter of `Timer` constructor consists in the interval between ticks. Also inside `MoveFunct` function, I'm calling a `Dispatcher` method otherwise it could not access UI thread.
In the sample I used a `TranslateTransform` which is better, in my opinion, than `Margin` manipulation because it requires to update the element whole visual tree.

Comment: The solution that you've posted partially solves the problem. I want the object to move when I hold the Up button/Down button/Left button/Right button and **not the object itself.**

Comment: With the same approach it should be possible. I'll write some code otherwise I'm sorry for the useless answer

Comment: I appreciate your effort. But, the answer that I'm looking for is through C# and not VB.NET. I somewhat tweaked my solution according to the previous link that you posted. I've also edited my question with a new problem that I'm facing. Anyway, thanks for your instant response.

Comment: The forgie me for vb.net, I used an old project (VS2013 does not allow WP Silverlight projects). However I was afraid of that problem with manipulation events: my previous answer was **wrong** and you can't just tweak it. Look at the new solution.

Comment: There seems to be an error in "new TimerCallback(MoveFunct)" it says that No overload for 'move' matches delegate 'System.Threading.TimerCallback'. My function's name is move so I've used move instead of MoveFunct.

Comment: @AnmolKumar corrected, I was missing a generic Object parameter in callback function signature

Comment: Still negative. No overload matches delegate System.Threading.TimerCallback....I already gave this modification a try.

Comment: Tried on a blank WP8 Silverlight project and it's working. I can't help you further then

Comment: Aah, I guess I had missed some part of your updated answer. It works now. Thanks for your time.